# Error: Task Token is required in `payload` for callback. Use JsonPath.taskToken to set the token

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-cdk

hi my state machine look like this

```
state_machine = sfn.StateMachine(
    self,
    "MyStateMachine",
    definition=tasks.LambdaInvoke(
        self,
        "MyLambdaTask",
        lambda_function=hello_function,
        integration_pattern=tasks.IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
        payload={   "payload.$": "$",
                    "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                    "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"},
    ).next(
    self,
    "MyStateMachine_step2",
    definition=tasks.LambdaInvoke(
        self,
        "MyLambdaTask2",
        lambda_function=hello_function,
        integration_pattern=tasks.IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
        payload={   "payload.$": "$",
                    "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                    "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"},
    )
        
        )
    )
)
```

on making build I am getting this error :

jsii.errors.JavaScriptError:
Error: Task Token is required in `payload` for callback. Use JsonPath.taskToken to set the token. I even tried to put task token into payload but nothing is working till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In payload you are defining

```
 "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"},
```

How does your $$ look like ? Does it have a Task.Token ?

You can test it by adding a variable into payload something like (not sure about the dot after $$, just try it out :)

```
"everything.$": "$$."
```

And then in the step, check the value of "everything" and see if it has the Task.Token value.

```
$ = access to current step input json
$$ = access to initial stepfunction input json
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty weird, the syntax is different between the AWS Console and the CDK for this,  so you'll want

> `"taskToken": sfn.JsonPath.taskToken`

instead of

> `"taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"`

(weirdly enough, you don't need the .$ at the end of they key when you specify it like this)